# Redirect output to file when there is additional prompt

Tags: linux, command-line

I'd like to save the output from running a specific command on the command line. However, after running the command, I am prompted to type in the name of my account to confirm that I would indeed like to run this command.

If I simply use `command > file.txt`, the prompt itself is saved to the file and I can't type the confirmation. What command can I use to save this output?

Comment: nb: you *can* type the confirmation, you'll just be doing it blind (without having seen the prompt). That said: you'll have to save the prompt to the file or pipe the output to a process that discards that first line (the prompt) and saves the rest to a file.

Comment: Have you written the command that does the prompting? Interactive prompts are always produced on the standard error stream (for this very reason). If you are able to modify the program, make it prompt on the standard error stream, or submit a bug report to this effect to the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tee`, which writes both to stdout and a file.

```
command | tee file.txt
```